# Adding values based on common keys using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I have 2 arrays `String key[]` , `long value[]` . keys can be duplicated . I need unique keys and their sum of the values in a map. Below is the code I am trying but i get Array out of bound exception

```
public HashMap < String, Long > getValueMap(String key[], long value[]) {
    Map newmap = new HashMap();
    long count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
            if (key[i] == key[j]) {
                count = count + value[j];
            }
        }
        newmap.put(key[i], count);

        count = 0;
    }
    return (HashMap < String, Long > ) newmap;

}


long[] value = {};
String key[] = {};
int i = 0;
        if(!worklogs.isEmpty()){
            for(Worklog wl:worklogs){
                value[i]=wl.getValue();
                key[i]=wl.getAuthor();i++;

            }
        }

HashMap < String, Long > newhm = getValueMap(key, value);
Iterator entries = newhm.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
    String newkey = (String) entry.getKey();
    Long newvalue = (Long) entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("Key = " + newkey + ", Value = " + newvalue);
}
```

The above code is modified to make it look simple. Please can someone help ?

Comment: At what line is the exception thrown

Comment: In one of your loops the length is variable, in the other it is hard coded to be 10. How long is the array you pass in?

Comment: @Floris the length is variable .. I have put it in a for loop just for displaying ... I am actually iterating a list of objects(wl)

Comment: Can you explain what the second block of code is attempting to do? It doesn't compile in Java - is it meant to...?

Comment: Why are you using primitive arrays and not an implementation of `List`?

Comment: But how long is it... And what is the value of I when it fails

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave My class is a bit complex so i have just pasted a part of it a method and how i am calling the method

Comment: OK, so I'm not certain, but doesn't long[] value={}; create an empty array? So, when you then try to access value[0] within the loop, it fails because there is no value[0]?

Comment: @AramKocharyan I had this logic ready of adding common elements in array

Comment: Hmm... Using Objects has usually solved any issues I've had with primitives giving me headaches.

Comment: I have edited the code ... Worklog is a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be caused because arrays value and key haven't  been initialized before trying to add values to them.

`long[] value= new long[10];`

`String key[]= new String[10];`

Why do you need to use arrays instead of Lists? Because if you need the length to ve variable I think it would be a more comfortable approach.

Comment: Ok i will try using List instead of arrays ,

Answer (score 1):

`Key[]` might be shorter than `value[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
     for(i,i<10,i++){
```

With

```
for(i, i<Value.length(); i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

Here array length equals 0

```
long[] value = {};
```

Here you try set value and get a error because array length == 0

```
value[i] = wl.getValue();
```

Use `value.length` instead of magic number 10

```
for(int i = 0; i < value.length; i++){  
   key[i] = wl.getAuthor();
}
```